# Neo4j/Cypher Conditional Statements for Loading Data

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j, is there a simple way to combine WHERE statements to avoid reading through the same file multiple times while simultaneously ignoring NULL values.

For example, is it possible to go through a CSV a single time, and do something like the following

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from "file" as line
WITH line, line.FirstNodeID as NodeOneID
WHERE NodeOneID IS NOT NULL
WITH NodeOneID
CREATE (n1:NodeOne { ID : NodeOneID })
WITH line, line.SecondNodeID as NodeTwoID
WHERE NodeTwoID IS NOT NULL
WITH NodeTwoID
CREATE (n2:NodeTwo { ID : NodeTwoID})
;
```

As of now, the LOAD script will exit if NodeOneID is null even if NodeTwoID is NOT null. How can I build in a simple if-else like condition where the LOAD script will load the proper nodes as long as NodeOneID or NodeTwoID is not null?

**UPDATE:** Just saw [CASE](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-expressions.html#syntax-simple-case). Gonna check this out real quick..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do something like this for each line.  If the value is not null put it in a collection of one.  Then if the collections have an item the node(s) is/are created and if they are empty no nodes are created.  If they both have values then both nodes are created.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from "file" as line
WITH line
, case when line.FirstNodeID is not null then [line] else [] end as NodeOneID
, case when line.SecondNodeID is not null then [line] else [] end as NodeTwoID
foreach(x in NodeOneID | CREATE (n1:NodeOne { ID : x.FirstNodeID }))
foreach(x in NodeTwoID | CREATE (n2:NodeTwo { ID : x.SecondNodeID }))
```

Comment: Is that memory efficient? Won't that store each line in separate lists? So for larger imports this might be devastating?

Comment: This is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from "file" as line
foreach(x in COALESCE(line.FirstNodeID)  | CREATE (:NodeOne { ID : x }))
foreach(x in COALESCE(line.SecondNodeID) | CREATE (:NodeTwo { ID : x }));
```

Comment: I think this looks nice and tidy; wish i had thought of it.